# React Native toggle that responds to tapping and swiping/sliding gestures

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to create a custom toggle component that will respond to tapping(or pressing) and swiping/ sliding gestures. The toggle should be able to be customizable in terms of its appearance, with different text and "on" styles, which is why I don't think the Switch component would work in my case.

What I am looking to do is something like this:
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UkRu.jpg)
If I swipe or click the red portion, it should toggle to the other side.

I am not too sure where to start (I am pretty new to React Native), so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you taken a look at [react-native-gesture-recognizers](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-gesture-recognizers)?

Comment: I'll definitely take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I've run into some errors (TransformError: using removed babel 5 option) so I think I'm going to abandon that route.

Comment: Have you looked at adding your own panResponder? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html